# Write a script to query nn tousands of entries in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a SQL query which works for single checks:
`SELECT trans_id from schema.table where trans_id like '%<trans_id>%'`
There're might be better approaches to query for, but that's not the point.

The database has aprox. 150k entries and I should check 30k of them if the trans_id exists.
The problem I face is, that I don't know if the normal approach with joining works, because the trans_id which have to be queried from are not in the database (unfortunately excel :/).

I'm not allowed to add them to the database to join them.

My idea was to create some kind of script which I trigger via psql: (researched)

```
psql -U postgres -d database -o /absolute_path/textfile.txt << EOF
Query1;
Query2;
Query ....;
EOF
```

But in my expectation that would result in writing 30k lines of the select statements to the EOF section. I doubt this works, not even talking about the effort.

also the Output should be routed to an local file, which shows:

- trans_id exists
- trans_id doesn't exists

Maybe some Loop with an array? But I don't now how.

Performance is not my goal in the first place.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: If you need to search for thousands of `trans_ids` in a table of hundreds of thousands, the best path is to load those thousands into a temp table and then perform a single query with a join to that temp table. Loading thousands of entries into a `LIKE ANY ()` or running thousands of individual SELECT statements is going to be slow and painful. Whatever you do, don't loop. Looping in a set based language is a last resort and is always the worst option.

Comment: "I doubt this works, not even talking about the effort."  Well, what happened when you tried it?  How much effort is involved in having your computer do 30000 rows of work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a query from DBA-Forum. Unfortunately after approx. 20sec query runtime I had timeout performance issues. Due I'm not allowed to adjust the config I wrote a looped script to workaround the problem.

This fitted my purposes best:

Solution as follows:

- create a conf file to provide all parameters of course
- usage of psycopg2 for database connects via postgres and python
- numpy for handling I/O files

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error
import numpy as np
from configparser import SafeConfigParser

def get_config_parameter(conf_file,section, parameter):
    config_object = SafeConfigParser()
    config_object.read(conf_file)
 
    return str(config_object.get(section ,parameter))

dbpassword = get_config_parameter('db.conf', 'PROD ENV', 'dbusername')
dbusername = get_config_parameter('db.conf', 'PROD ENV', 'dbusername')
dbhost = get_config_parameter('db.conf', 'PROD ENV', 'dbhost')
dbname = get_config_parameter('db.conf', 'PROD ENV', 'dbname')
input_file_name = get_config_parameter('db.conf', 'PROD ENV', 'input_file_name')
output_result_file = get_config_parameter('db.conf', 'PROD ENV','output_result_file')
chunksize = 500


eculist = np.loadtxt(input_file_name, dtype="str")

ecu_chunks = ""
ecu_chunk_list = []

for ecu in eculist:
        ecu_chunk_list.append(f"('{ecu}'), ")



def query(dbusername, dbpassword, dbhost, dbname, query_input):
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user=dbusername, password=dbpassword, host=dbhost, database=dbname)
        # create a cursor to perform database operations
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        print("CONNECTED:", connection.get_dsn_parameters(), ": \n")

        try:
            query = f"WITH list(pattern) as (values {query_input}) SELECT pattern, EXISTS (select 1 FROM mule.transactions WHERE transaction_id LIKE '%'||pattern||'%') FROM list;"
            print('query in progress... please wait')
            cursor.execute(query)

            result = str(cursor.fetchall())

            return result

        except (Exception, Error) as error:
            print("SQL: Error while executing query:", error)

    except (Exception, Error) as error:
        print("NOT CONNECTED: Error while connection to Database:", error)

    finally:
        if connection:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("Database connection closed!")

result = ""
out_text = ""

for i in range(0,len(ecu_chunk_list),chunksize):
    test = str(ecu_chunk_list[i:i+chunksize]).replace('", "','').replace('"','')
    length = len(test)
    test = test[1:length -3]
    result = query(dbusername,dbpassword,dbhost,dbname, test)

    out_text = out_text + result

save_file = open(output_result_file, 'w+')
save_file.write(out_text)
save_file.close()
```

Of course you can get rid of all the fail-safe but I think it's useful.